# discord.py bot executing command twice

Tags: python, discord.py

When I made cogs, my bot started to executing command twice and I'm started getting error Unknown Message. I don't know how to fix it, pls help me !
In the embed_commands i have imports, just do not write them there. I don't see any problem in code, maybe I don't understand something. Also I don't find any answer to my issue. Some people says that is because 2 bots running but it is not true, so pls help me !

main.py

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from cogs import embed_command, music

cogs = [embed_command, music]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.remove_command("help")

# for i in range(len(cogs)):
#     cogs[i].setup(client)


for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
    else:
        print(f'Unable to load {filename[:-3]}')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("\n\tOnline")

client.run('token')
```

embed_command

```
class Embed(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.client.user:
            return
        await self.client.process_commands(message)

    @commands.command()
    async def embed(self, ctx):
        embed_question = discord.Embed(
            title="Enter a title of embed message: ",
            description="||This request will be canceled in 10 seconds!||"
        )
        embed1 = await ctx.send(embed=embed_question)
        try:
            msg = await self.client.wait_for("message", check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=10)

            converter = commands.ColourConverter()
            colour_object = await converter.convert(ctx, f'{msg.content.split("/", 3)[2]}')

            embed_question_answer = discord.Embed(
                title=msg.content.split("/", 3)[0],
                description=msg.content.split("/", 3)[1],
                color=colour_object
            )
            # embed_question_answer.add_field(name=msg.content.split("/", 3)[2], value=msg.content.split("/", 3)[3],
            #                                 inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed_question_answer)
            # await msg.delete()
            # await ctx.message.delete()
            # await embed1.delete()
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            timeout_embed = discord.Embed(
                title="",
                description="***Отмена операции из-за долгого ожидания.***",
                color=0x2f3136
            )
            await ctx.send(embed=timeout_embed, delete_after=5)
            await embed1.delete()
            await ctx.message.delete()

    @commands.command()
    async def clear(self, ctx, amount=5):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        embed_answer = discord.Embed(
            title="",
            description=f"***{amount} сообщений(-я, -е) было удалено.***",
            color=0x2f3136
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed_answer, delete_after=5)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Embed(client))
```

Traceback

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\Python\pythonProject\InfinityBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "Z:\Python\pythonProject\InfinityBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "Z:\Python\pythonProject\InfinityBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `client.process_commands` inside of `Cogs`, that's only for `on_message` events that are in a Python file by themselves. Remove that line from your `on_message` event and it should stop executing twice.

From the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=process_commands#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working):

> Alternatively, you can place your on_message logic into a listener. In this setup, you should not manually call bot.process_commands().